How to retrieve paragraph fields from a content type in a custom block type?
I have data entered in a custom paragraph type in a custom content type. This data successfully presents in several areas: a node template, a view page, and view blocks. I also want to present this data in a custom block type that can be placed with layout builder by the content editor. I have successfully done this using the entity reference field for the content type. This, too, displays correctly when the block is placed.
My question is that because I need to access the individual paragraph fields in the content type from my custom block, is there a {% for... %} code I can implement to do this?
My block--programs.html.twig:
{% block content %}
    <div{{ content_attributes }}>{{ content }}</div>
{% endblock %}

My node--programs.html.twig:
{% for paragraph in content.field_programs['#items'] %}...
Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

You need to find out how you can preprocess variables from PHP and pass them on to your template. Drilling this from within Twig should be considered bad pratice, as you tend to circumvent access and caching that way. Look up Drupal preprocess. And maybe get to use either Xdebug or the Devel module's debug functions to be placed directly in your code for inspecting variables.
